# How to stop running a tool when a certain text prints out?

Tags: python, bash

I run a Python-based tool in terminal, and I want it to stop when the tool prints a certain message.

I want to stop the command to measure time with 'time' command, and I want to automate this measurement process to prevent stopping the function manually. It doesn't make sense when you try to measure time while trying to be fast for CTRL+C...

Until now, I have used `time command1 .....` and stopped the command manually.

I expect to create a bash script that runs several times (can be done easily with the loops), stops when a certain message appears, and prints or saves the time (user+sys).

Comment: I'm not sure if I've caught the question but, you can monitor the output of the python-based tool and then kill it when needed. There are several ways to achieve this, e.g., you can buffer the output of the tool in a tmp file and periodically check it.

Comment: Who did write the tool? is this a question about bash ou about python?

Comment: You can kill any process from command-line or bash script with `kill`. Now you need to write a child script that listens to the output and performs that kill.

Comment: Note that many well-behaved programs should quit if the piped listener stops or closes its standard input, eg when you `gunzip bigfile.gz -c | head` gunzip will terminate quicklywhen head has printed 10 lines. You could use `grep -m1` as the listener?

Comment: @danlor: Actually the tool that I am using does not create any output file, because it is a visualisation tool.  
@iuridiniz: The tool is not written by me. It is a question about bash, because this tool can be used from terminal and i want to use `time` command which is in bash.  
@GemTaylor: Yeah that is what I want. I can search for commands that can listen the output. And I haven't thought about piping before, I didn't know such case that you mentioned is possible. I will search about them, thanks...